# Styling placeholder independently

Tags: html, input, placeholder

Is there a way to style placeholder in `input` elements independently of the text that appears when a user input something? For example, I want to style an `input` element with `text-align: right`, but let the placeholder text appear as `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by using `::placeholder`.

```css
input {
  text-align: right;
}

input::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label>
      Name
      <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe">
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Source:** http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/